# Genral understanding: Classes in SV

Tags: system-verilog

My question is about classes in SV.

In SV classes:

Are the functions and the variables( if not declared static) are they automatic by default???

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the SV documentation, what did you find?

Comment: I think they ought to be automatic. I want to confirm that

Answer (score 1):

Methods ( functions or tasks) in classes always have automatic lifetimes and the variables declared inside them default in having automatic lifetimes. **Caution**: functions and tasks declared outside of classes have the opposite static lifetime, but there are a number of ways of changing the default back to automatic.

Comment: Thanks very much Dave for clarification